# SkLearn - Using RegressorChain with ColumnTransformer in Pipelines?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I'm having problems using sklearn's `RegressorChain` (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.RegressorChain.html), and unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation/examples about this.

The documentation states indirectly (through the `set_params` method) that it can be used with Pipelines. My pipeline has:

```py
ct = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('scaler', MinMaxScaler(), numerical_columns),
        ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(), ['day_of_week']),
    ],
    remainder='passthrough'
)

cv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits = groups.nunique()) #groups by date

pipeline = make_pipeline(ct, lgb.LGBMRegressor(random_state=42))

target_transform_output = TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=pipeline, transformer=PowerTransformer())
```

and then I do:

```py
chain_regressor = RegressorChain(base_estimator=target_transform_output , order=[1,0,2])
chain_regressor.fit(X, y)
```

In the above, both X and y are pandas Dataframes, and y has 3 target columns.

When I run the code, I get a python stack trace caused by the `fit()` call, starting in `__init.py__` in `_get_column_indices(X, key)` when doing `all_columns = X.columns`. The error is:

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'`

and further down at the end of the stack trace:

`ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames`

I assume this is because the `ColumnTransformer` returns ndarrays, a well-known problem. Does this mean that the `RegressorChain` can't be used with the `ColumnTransformer`?

After this, I removed the column transformer step from the pipeline and tried again, and without the `ColumnTransformer` everything works fine (even the `TransformedTargetRegressor`).

Any help, ideas or workaround appreciated.

Comment: Why not just turn your numpy arrays into pandas dataframes?

Comment: Hi @wundermahn. As I state above:

"both X and y are pandas Dataframes, and y has 3 target columns."

I am not using ndarrays anywhere in my code.

Comment: Then how are you getting an error for a numpy array? As you state above, _When I run the code, I get a python stack trace caused by the fit()..._, `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'`

Comment: The ColumnTransformer outputs ndarrays, even if you give it Pandas Dataframes. Well known issue with sklearn, reported since 2015. What I'm trying to understand is if there's any workaround (or find an error I'm making) so that they can be used with RegressorChain. Check: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5523 , for example.

Comment: Exactly what I said in the first comment. Why not store your output from ColumnTransformer into a dataframe?

Comment: That probably works, true --  but it does break the possibility of having an end-to-end pipeline that I can also use for inferencing. I'd have to serialize both the CT's state + fitted regressor's. Was looking for something that didn't break with the idea of having a single pipeline, tbh. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It's not the `ColumnTransformer` outputting arrays that's the issue here, it's the `RegressorChain` itself transforming the input into arrays.  The one-hot encoding could be done before the regressor chain instead of inside it for each regression.  The scaling probably should be applied to the targets in "later" regressions, so specifying the columns using a `make_column_selector` for numerics would probably be better.

Comment: @BenReiniger thanks for the insight, but one q -- so where's the failure? do you know? Considering my code snippet, what's the component trying to access the column list?

Comment: And why does the RegressorChain if I call it directly without using the ColumnTransformer?  I do think the issue is the ColumnTransformer outputting ndarray and the chain relying on a DataFrame.

Would appreciate detail.

Answer (score 1):

You have the issue the wrong way around: it's not that `ColumnTransformer` outputs an array and `RegressorChain` expected a dataframe; rather, the `RegressorChain` converts your input to an array before calling your pipeline, and so your `ColumnTransformer` doesn't get a dataframe as input and cannot use your column-name specifications.

You could just specify the columns by index or callable in the `ColumnTransformer`.  But I think in this case, you have two unfortunate side-effects:

1. For each target, you are re-encoding `day_of_week` and re-scaling each independent variable (not wrong, just a little wasteful), and
2. you never scale the targets, even when they are used as independent variables for "later" targets' regressions (not wrong for a tree-based model like your lightGBM [in fact, for LGBM, why bother scaling at all?], but other models might suffer from not scaling those).

(1) can be fixed by preprocessing as a pipeline step *before* `RegressorChain`.  (2) can be fixed by changing the scaler's column specification to a callable, below using the helper `make_column_selector`.  Doing that fix for (2) does end up re-calculating the scalings at each step (hurting (1) again), but I think in the end that's a bigger deal (if you wanted to use something other than a tree model at some point).
So I would suggest instead:

```py
encoder = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(), ['day_of_week']),
    ],
    remainder='passthrough',
)

scale_nums = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('scaler', MinMaxScaler(), make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number)),
    ],
    remainder='passthrough',
)

modeling_pipe = make_pipeline(scale_nums, lgb.LGBMRegressor(random_state=42))

target_transform_output = TransformedTargetRegressor(
    regressor=modeling_pipe,
    transformer=PowerTransformer(),
)

final_pipeline = make_pipeline(encoder, target_transform_output)
```